# Can I assert within OpenMP 2.0 loops?

Tags: c++

It seems to compile, but I just wanted to ask if there are other considerations or reasons why this might not work as expected:

```
std::vector<int> myvec(100,1)
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
for (int i = 0; i < (int) myvec.size(); ++i)
{
  assert(myvec[i] == 1);
}
```

Comment: AFAIK, worst case scenario is that you get a garbled error message because it fails on several threads at the same time. If you want to be sure, preprocess the file and see what the macro looks like once expanded.

Comment: normally `assert` just a `if` statement with `printf/abort`, they should be threadsafe.

Comment: It's usually a good idea to have all your threads follow the same path. When an assert fails though the whole program will fail so it should be ok. Although you may wish to write a custom assert where the `printf` is in a `critical` block (@zneak's comment). Danger situations to watch for are barriers in `if` statements and the like where threads can get stuck waiting indefinitely.